# scene gets not destroyed when loading another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene, scene-manager

I have a problem with the ScenManager of my unity android app.
When I start a new Scene the old scene is activ and work but the new scene is shown an work. I want that only the new scene work.

```
// here I load the new Scene
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
```

I tried a lot but in every I found the old scene gets atomatically destroyed.

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking. You say "I want that only the new scene work", then you say "I tried a lot but in every I found the old scene gets atomatically destroyed", so its unclear whether you want the old scene around or not.

Comment: I am sorry my Englisch is not the best. In everything I found the old scene not work when you start the new scene but in my case the old scene is working even though i started the new scene and i dont know why

Comment: Do you mean that objects in the "old scene" are still around in the newly loaded scene? I'm having a hard time understanding how two scenes could be active at the same time.

Comment: The advantage of having many scenes is you can actually have your UI etc as a scene, so its the same thing through out your whole game

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Scenes have to be unloaded manually, otherwise they will stay active. Check out the [SceneManager documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html).

In your case, unloading the old scene using
`SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(sceneName);`
should work.

You can also try to experiment with the `mode` parameter. But as `Single` is the default value it properbly does not what you want:
`SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);`

Comment: The default mode is `LoadSceneMode.Single` anyway. Scenes do **not** have to be actively unloaded when using `LoadScene `without the mode parameter (equals passing in `Single`)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with derHugo.  You do not need to manually unload scenes if you use LoadSceneMode.Single.

See this documentation related to OnDestroy as well:

"Destroying the attached Behaviour will result in the game or Scene receiving OnDestroy.

OnDestroy occurs when a Scene or game ends. If a Scene is closed and a new Scene is loaded the OnDestroy call will be made.

When built as a standalone application OnDestroy calls are made when Scenes end. A Scene ending typically means a new Scene is loaded."

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html

In terms of solving your problem, use LoadSceneMode.Single.  In you want to keep the previous scene active, use LoadSceneMode.Additive.